# Custom UI elements

Tags: qt, user-interface

I am new to GUI programming. I am now able to make simple GUI applications with QT. My question is, how do programmers make custom-designed UI elements.

Is it the QML?

How can I make custom-designed UI elements? For example a button which has animations on hover and has custom color scheme or a combobox which opens with an animation and looks completely different.

Overall, How are UI elements made in a programming language from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many things (e.g. hover button) you can implement using style-sheets.

In this example the background image is replaced on mouse over:

```
QPushButton
{
    image: url(:/res/button.png);
}

QPushButton:hover
{
   image: url(:/res/button_h.png);
}
```

Take a look at Qt State machines and animation framework.

If nothing helps, subclass a widget and re-implement event handlers (most probably paint-event)